# Trapping floating point exceptions with LAPACK

Tags: fortran, lapack

I have a program that uses LAPACK, or optionally compiles a subset of LAPACK. I would like to enable gfortran's `-ffpe-trap=...` (or similar with other compilers) to trap floating point exceptions and help me catch bugs and errors. However, LAPACK does not like this (https://github.com/Reference-LAPACK/lapack-release/blob/lapack-3.7.1/INSTALL/make.inc.gfortran):

```
#  Note: During a regular execution, LAPACK might create NaN and Inf
#  and handle these quantities appropriately. As a consequence, one
#  should not compile LAPACK with flags such as -ffpe-trap=overflow.
```

I thought I could try compiling LAPACK *without* the flag, and then my program with it, but it seems it is the flags used for the main program that rule, and I get exceptions from LAPACK code. I've tried static and dynamic linking.

Is there some way I can use `-ffpe-trap=...` in my program but "disable" it for code inside LAPACK chain?

Comment: You need finer handling for that, a simple compiler flag is not sufficient. Look at the ieee_ modules in Fortran 2003.

Comment: @VladimirF Thanks for the pointer. Trying to use the ieee_exceptions module now... Is it possible to somehow set the halting mode in a subroutine and have it survive for the rest of the main program? I have many programs that use the same "startup" subroutine. I'd rather modify this than each main program...